# PHP show values of associative array when one of the values equals a specified value

Tags: php, mysql, associative-array

I have a Mysql Recordset that I have put into an associative array so that I can reuse it over and over.

I used this function to put the values into the array:

```
while(($Comments[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsComments)) || array_pop($Comments));
```

Here is what the print_r($Comments) displays

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [CommentID] => 10 [Comment] => Ouch [CommentAuthor] => Randy Krohn [CommentDate] => 2010-10-06 17:19:49 [ID] => 1231 [CategoryID] => 42 ) [1] => Array ( [CommentID] => 12 [Comment] => This is the Dirty Duck [CommentAuthor] => John Lemoine [CommentDate] => 2010-10-06 17:22:43 [ID] => 1411 [CategoryID] => 42 ) [2] => Array ( [CommentID] => 13 [Comment] => Talk about deja vu! [CommentAuthor] => dber [CommentDate] => 2010-10-06 17:24:48 [ID] => 1473 [CategoryID] => 42 ) )
```

I am looping through a list of images, and I want to display only the comments associated with an images specified ImageID (for example 1473).

I need to display only the ones where the ID is equal to a specified value?

This must be easy, but for some reason, it is just flying over my head.

Thanks for you help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way is to loop through 'Comments' associative array (aka dictionary) with `foreach` and check the value of 'ID' key, if it matches the desired value, print the value of 'Comment' key:

```
$imageId = 1473;
foreach($Comments as $comment) {
    if($comment['ID'] == $imageId) {
        echo $comment['Comment'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  I knew it was simple, I just couldn't grasp it this morning.  Exactly what I wanted.

Comment: Why would this function not include the first value in the recordset?while(($Comments[] = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsComments)) || array_pop($Comments));

Comment: First record should be included unless you called mysql_fetch_assoc or any other fetch method that would have moved the result set pointer forward somewhere prior to this but after calling query.